# beamer: click number to go to respective frame / dynamic labels

Tags: beamer, links

I am developing the following style:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny


\title{Title}
\author{Ricardo Cruz}
\date{}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% SIDEBAR

\newlength\swidth
\setlength\swidth{1.2cm}    

\newlength\theight
\setlength\theight{1.0cm}   

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerleftmargin
\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\newlength\sheight

\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=\swidth}
\setbeamerfont{sidebar right}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\setlength\sheight{\dimexpr(\paperheight-\theight)/(\inserttotalframenumber-1) \relax}
\vspace{\theight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\sheight]
    \foreach \i in {2,...,\inserttotalframenumber} {
        \def\pgnbr{\inserttotalframenumber - \i-1}
        \ifnum\i=\insertframenumber
            \filldraw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[white,anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \else
            \draw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth-0.07cm,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% TITLE

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-\beamerleftmargin}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth-0.08cm,\theight-0.05cm);
\node[anchor=mid] at (\paperwidth/2,\theight/2) {\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%%

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{First}
First
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
Second
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third}
Third
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I am pretty happy with it. (The idea is to have many slides and so the sidebar numbers will not look as big.)

But now, I don't know how to make the sidebar numbers clickable to go to their respective frame.

I know I could place a `\label{frame1}`, `\label{frame2}`, etc inside each frame, and then use a `\hyperlink{frame1}{1}`, `\hyperlink{frame2}{2}`, etc, but I want it to be dynamic. How can I define dynamic label such as `\label{frame\insertframenumber}` and hyperlink them?

- **UPDATE** *

Actually, it seems dynamic labels work fine on latex (sorry for not trying!). But how can I define automatically a label for each frame without inserting them manually like in the following code?

I have tried placing them inside `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{...}` but that did not work...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny


\title{Title}
\author{Ricardo Cruz}
\date{}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% SIDEBAR

\newlength\swidth
\setlength\swidth{1.2cm}    

\newlength\theight
\setlength\theight{1.0cm}   

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerleftmargin
\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\newlength\sheight

\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=\swidth}
\setbeamerfont{sidebar right}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\setlength\sheight{\dimexpr(\paperheight-\theight)/(\inserttotalframenumber-1) \relax}
\vspace{\theight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\sheight]
    \foreach \i in {2,...,\inserttotalframenumber} {
        \def\pgnbr{\inserttotalframenumber - \i-1}
        \ifnum\i=\insertframenumber
            \filldraw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[white,anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\hyperlink{frame\i}{\number\numexpr\i-1}};
        \else
            \draw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth-0.07cm,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\hyperlink{frame\i}{\number\numexpr\i-1}};
        \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% TITLE

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-\beamerleftmargin}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth-0.08cm,\theight-0.05cm);
\node[anchor=mid] at (\paperwidth/2,\theight/2) {\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%%

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{First}
\label{frame1}
First
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
\label{frame2}
Second
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third}
\label{frame3}
Third
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beamer already has hypertargets for each page. Use \hyperlink{Navigation\i}{...} inside a node, unless you start having multipage frames.

Comment: Did you try `miniframes` before? If so, what is the difference between `miniframes` and your expectation?

Comment: @JohnKormylo that worked out perfectly! Please submit as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a `\rule` inside a node one can click anywhere inside the rectangle.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny


\title{Title}
\author{Ricardo Cruz}
\date{}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% SIDEBAR

\newlength\swidth
\setlength\swidth{1.2cm}    

\newlength\theight
\setlength\theight{1.0cm}   

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerleftmargin
\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\newlength\sheight

\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=\swidth}
\setbeamerfont{sidebar right}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\setlength\sheight{\dimexpr(\paperheight-\theight)/(\inserttotalframenumber-1) \relax}
\vspace{\theight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\sheight]
    \foreach \i in {2,...,\inserttotalframenumber} {
        \def\pgnbr{\inserttotalframenumber - \i-1}
        \ifnum\i=\insertframenumber
            \node[draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,above right] at (0,\pgnbr) {\hyperlink{Navigation\i}{\rule{\swidth}{\sheight}}};
            \node[white,anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \else
            \node[draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,above right] at (0,\pgnbr) {\hyperlink{Navigation\i}{\color{white}\rule{\swidth}{\sheight}}};
            \node[anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% TITLE

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-\beamerleftmargin}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth-0.08cm,\theight-0.05cm);
\node[anchor=mid] at (\paperwidth/2,\theight/2) {\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%%

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{First}
\label{frame1}
First
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
\label{frame2}
Second
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third}
\label{frame3}
Third
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You also might take a look at `\beamer@startpageofframe`.